# Socks5 proxy "Dante" leaves many child processes stuck in FIN_WAIT2 / CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: linux, socks, dante

I'm running dante v1.2.1 as a SOCKS proxy server. The proxy works fine but at the end of the day there are around 40-50 or more child processes of sockd running even though there are no active connections.

lsof shows that the child processes all have sockets in the CLOSE_WAIT and FIN_WAIT2 state. These child processes stay in this state unless I manually killall/restart the daemon.

I'm running Gentoo Linux on a 2.6.24-23-xen kernel. I recently upgraded from dante v1.1.19-r4 which was giving me the exact same problem.

Is this a configuration issue with Dante, my system, or is it a coding issue in the dante source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLOSE_WAIT means the other side closed the connection. The socket will be closed after the local program closes the socket descriptor. There is no time-out for CLOSE_WAIT, so process can be stuck with a socket in this state indefinitely. When you kill the process and its children, they close sockets and they get closed. Run `lsof` and see if the children have the sockets open. If they do, then it looks like a bug in their code.

As for FIN_WAIT2, it's when local side waits for FIN,ACK from the other side to confirm closing the connection. However, there's a system-wide time-out on this state (see `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout`), which is by default 60s, so nothing should be stuck in this phase longer than a minute. BUT if seems that it's possible to code a program in such a way that a half-closed connection looks like an active one to the kernel, so the time-out won't kick in. Again, it would seem that you've found a bug.